# Display items as soon as it gets the first result from http GET

Tags: angular, http, ionic3

So I'm calling my API through my ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.http
        .get<Config>('http://localhost:5000/api/user/announcements')
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.information = data.announcements;
            this.datalength = data.announcements.length;
            this.loader.dismiss();
        });
}
```

and my html looks like this:

```
<ion-card [@flipInX]="flipInX" class="list" *ngFor="let item of information | slice:0:slice;" text-wrap>
        <ion-card-header text-wrap>
            <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: -25px; font-size: 16px;">
            Date posted: {{item.date}}
        </ion-card-content>
        <button ion-button clear end style="float: right;" (click)="showDetails(item.title, item.date, item.content)">View</button>
    </ion-card>
```

I noticed that it takes quite a while to display my data, which makes for a bad user experience. How do I resolve this so that at least the initial items get displayed while the rest load up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If `no pagination` is applicable from backend**, then You can take `*ngIf` and check the length of `information`

If length is `0` you can show a `static` value.

```
  <ion-content *ngIf="!information.length">
        <ion-card text-wrap>
            <ion-card-header text-wrap>
                <h2>{{Laoding}}</h2>
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: -25px; font-size: 16px;">
                Loading
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-content>
```

If length is not `0` you can show your `value` and the data gets automatically updated.

```
<ion-content *ngIf="information.length">
    <ion-card [@flipInX]="flipInX" class="list" *ngFor="let item of information | slice:0:slice;" text-wrap>
        <ion-card-header text-wrap>
            <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: -25px; font-size: 16px;">
            Date posted: {{item.date}}
        </ion-card-content>
        <button ion-button clear end style="float: right;" (click)="showDetails(item.title, item.date, item.content)">View</button>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

I added conditions using `*ngIf="information.length"` && `*ngIf="!information.length"`

**Note:** It will be good to use pagination from the Backend.

Comment: I'll try the ngIf part and see if it works for me. Unfortunately, I can't touch the backend part, I'll try to suggest if they'll change it so that it supports pagination.

Comment: you can even add a `loading` image instead of `text` to make it more attractive to user

Comment: Well I did add some sort of loading modal that displays while it's loading up the data. Unfortunately, the ngIf doesn't work. It still wont display anything even if there's some data loaded already

Comment: Then there must be an error in the modal you added. Did it work with normal text?

Comment: This is strange: it works and the data I want to see gets shown briefly, because it only works when I press F5 (page refresh)

Comment: means, I didnt get you? I think you have some issue integrating your modal

Comment: removed my loading spinner modal now. It might be a connection issue. Not sure yet

Comment: okay check console and check for any errors. You can vote my answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything in this, the thing you can do either show some static content until you will get response from backend or just show `Loader` kind of image to tell user that he has to wait for some time to get data.

to use some static content you can use your code like this -

```
<ion-card [@flipInX]="flipInX" class="list" *ngFor="let item of information | slice:0:slice;" text-wrap>
        <ion-card-header text-wrap>
            <h2>{{item?.title || '-'}}</h2>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content style="margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: -25px; font-size: 16px;">
            Date posted: {{item?.date || '-'}}
        </ion-card-content>
        <button ion-button clear end style="float: right;" (click)="showDetails(item.title, item.date, item.content)">View</button>
    </ion-card>
```

Comment: well, OP *could* do something, but only by heavily changing the way the backend responds to the request (by streaming data), which is quite a broad change ofc.

Comment: As to the part where the user "waits for some time", the temporary workaround I have is to have a loading spinner show, and once the data is ready, it dismisses itself and shows the rendered page data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common type of question with different approaches.

1. easily you can declare a boolean variable. And it becomes true when the api data responded. Use this boolean as `*ngIf` for the div of the `ion-card`
2. Use a library ng-busy . shows a loader whenever a data is loading. I hope this one is better for a better ux. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-busy
3. Paginate over the api response. So some initial items displayed and the later get loaded when the user needs.  http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google